# How to get Visual Studio Unit Test to copy a file to the tests area? (which works when running/debugging)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

BACKGROUND: I have a sqlite file that is marked as COPY in it's properties.  When I debug my WinForms application in VS2008 (or run it) it does the right thing and copy it to the debug/run area.

QUESTION: When I run unit tests (using VS2008 unit tests) it is not performing this copy.  Anyone know how to get this working?  So that my sqlite database file will be copied across before VS2008 tries to run the unit tests

Comment: This is a similar question to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541096/visual-studio-unit-tests-loading-resources-in-the-project

Comment: or you could just add a post build event in debug mode doing the copy (probably not what you're looking for though...)

Comment: I'm finding that my file is going to "Project1_UnitTests\bin\Debug" whereas the test is trying to find it under "TestResults\Username_PCName_datetime\Out"..???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must either docorate your test with the DeploymentItemAttribute or configure deployment using the .testrunconfig file.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489712/ms-test-newbie-question/1489745#1489745) for more details.

Comment: add the DeploymentItem attribute to the test(s) in question