# VS.Net 2008 Unit testing path problem

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I want to have a good test setup but, I can't find a way to put files in the "In" folder under TestResuls.

How do I put files in the "In" folder.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489712/ms-test-newbie-question/1489745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will give you the location of the *out* folder - working out the in folder should be easy from there

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: Thank you that will be useful but, that is not what I asked. How do I get files automatically copied in to the "In" folder. 

Thanks